# VS2010 could not debug asp.net mvc 3 project

Tags: asp.net, iis

the error "unable to start debugging on the web server. the web server could not find the requested resource" came out whenever i click the debug button or f5. i have check through the application pool it was fine. it was able to debug by using the VS server but when it changes to IIS its not debugging and the above error came out. when i ask my friends to try out the website, he was able to run it. But when i tried only the directory came out. I have been encountering this problem for quite some time, wasnt able to solve it.Please Help me.

Comment: Have you got MVC 3 installed on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things we commonly make sure are set when we run into this kind of error.

1) Under the projects properties->Web tab make sure that the appropriate 'Debuggers' are enabled.

2) Make sure the project is set to launch a file in the website that you are looking to debug. (this one may be because of the odd layout of where our entry point is but its worth mentioning).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching it to your IIS worker process for the application by going to debug -> attach to process -> and selecting the w3wp.exe that is running your app pool for the application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows 7 or Windows Vista? If so, you need to run Visual Studio in admin mode to debug using IIS.

To start VS as an admin, right click it and select "Run as Administrator".

Comment: i am using windows 7 i did run it on admin mode the problem still exist. thanks for your advice anyway.

Comment: Have you tried just running (not debugging) the app in IIS? Does that work?